# Send SQL Query and Wait For Response VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net

Is there anyway to send a SQL query for a VB.NET application and not continue with the code until a response is received?

This would be using the ExecuteNonQuery Command so it 'should' return a row count?

Or does the code automatically wait for a response?

Regards,

James

Comment: It should wait for a response; have you been trying this out yourself and seen differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the .NET code will automatically wait for the response and will not execute until response has been received. In .Net 4.5 async has been added by using which you can go ahead before respose is received you need to learn more about code execution of .NET. PLease refer to MSDN or search on google for more details.